# Compilation error when compiling libvpx for FFMPEG

Tags: compiler-errors, ffmpeg, nasm, yasm, libvpx

I'm compiling FFMPEG on my 64bit Ubuntu 14 machine. Everything compiled well, except for the libvpx library, which keeps throwing errors:

```
[AS] vp9/common/x86/vp9_subpixel_8t_ssse3.asm.o
vp9/common/x86/vp9_subpixel_8t_ssse3.asm:856: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error
vp9/common/x86/vp9_subpixel_8t_ssse3.asm:897: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error
vp9/common/x86/vp9_subpixel_8t_ssse3.asm:970: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error
vp9/common/x86/vp9_subpixel_8t_ssse3.asm:1002: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error
vp9/common/x86/vp9_subpixel_8t_ssse3.asm:340: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
vp9/common/x86/vp9_subpixel_8t_ssse3.asm:457: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
vp9/common/x86/vp9_subpixel_8t_ssse3.asm:897: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
vp9/common/x86/vp9_subpixel_8t_ssse3.asm:1002: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
make[1]: *** [vp9/common/x86/vp9_subpixel_8t_ssse3.asm.o] Error 1
make: *** [.DEFAULT] Error 2
```

I followed this guide: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu
I don't know what this error means, but read somewhere that compiling libvpx with NASM is broken, but I don't know how to compile it otherwise. Installing version 1.2 or 1.1 makes no difference whatsoever. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Compiling it with Yasm did the trick:

```
PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin" ./configure --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" --disable-examples
PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin" make
```

Assuming Yasm is compiled in the home directory